# Use Post Request to retrieve data and return a List

Tags: c#, post, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a personal project learning on xamarin. So basically what I'm trying to do is getting some data from some api. So the method must be "POST" and also send a few headers. The response should be a token and a list of things. I tried wrapping my head around this problem but I couldn't figure it out. 
I searched a lot and found a few things which helped me get here with my code :

```
public async Task<List<Things>> GetThingsAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("xxx", "xxx");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("xxx", xxx);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent("");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var json = await client.PostAsync("https://blabla/bla/", content);

        var br = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Things>>(json);
        return br;

    }
```

Returning the `br` will generate this error:

> Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'string'

I tried using `JsonSerializerSettings` but I couldn't figure it out. So guys am I in the right track? Am I missing something or this approach is completely wrong?! Thanks In advance.

Jason answer solved this case. Now about navigating to another page I use this command :

```
public ICommand GetThingsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                things = await _apiServices.GetThingsAsync();
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SinglePage());
            });
        }
    }
```

The binding of the data must be made at the SinglePage but it throws me an exception when I return the `br`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostAsync` returns a [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx), which you can use to retrieve the actual content of the response

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("xxx", "xxx");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("xxx", xxx);

    HttpContent content = new StringContent("");
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://blabla/bla/", content);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var br = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Things>>(json);
    return br;
```

Comment: are you sure your json is getting deserialized properly?  You need to try and catch the actual underlying exception.  There are multiple posts here and elsewhere about dealing with the unhelpful "break state" message

Comment: a page is just a class, you can pass data via the constructor, a public property, a public method, etc.  Have you actually used the debugger to step through your code, verifying the deserialization and identifying which line causes the crash?

Comment: Yes of course I did. The json I get is valid and the crush happens just as soon as I "step into"  `return br`. I already tried validating the json and it's valid. I thought It had something to do with the GetThingsCommand interface. :/

Comment: put a breakpoint on the things assignment and determine if it crashes there, or on the PushAsync.  Add a try/catch around that block to see if you can see the exception

Comment: I think you should create a Repository class which holds your task. Create another Service class with a task which will call your Repository task.
Once in your view model, just inject your service into it with dependency service and await the result of the method.
Affect the result of the task (your method in your repo called from your injected service) to a list that you're binding to in your page which has this vm as bindingContext

Comment: @Jason I figured out where my problem was. I did exactly what you said. I tried to try and catch the json and I found the problem. The json was not in the desired format even though it was validated. Looks like I have a lot to learn. 
So thanks again :)